# Loading external XAML file into a WPF project? The file is our "styles"

Tags: wpf, xaml

Has anyone had experience, or is it even possible to load an external XAML file into a WPF project from a hosted website.

We are wondering because we are defining the XAML file as our "styles".  We would like a person not familiar with XAML to edit the file and then we don't have to redeploy the whole application, but next time the application loads it will just reference the changed XAML file.

Or is this not possible because the XAML files are compiled into the project?

Or would an option be to load an external XML file in code behind and populate our "style" properties that way?  Is this possible?

We currently are using ResourceDictionary and calling an internal XAML file in the application, but we would like a more dynamic solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using `XamlReader.Load` you can use the XAML parser. There is a performance hit from parsing `XAML` instead of `BAML`, and downloading a file from the network could negatively impact the (in my experience) often already slow startup times for WPF applications. The blog entry below provides a nice explanation of dynamically loading resource dictionaries.

http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2011/09/02/xamlreader-looseresourcedictionaryfiles-parsercontext/